# nodejs node-hid using the usb device VID/PID could not open

Tags: node.js, usb, hid

i have a usb rfid reader, it read rfid tag work well in notepad or ms word. after install nodejs node-hid,code like below

[image]

its work well and get result below.

[image]

so i  use this vid and pid ,code like this.
[image]

but show error.i use os win10 64, npm version 3.10.10 ,node version 6.10.0
[image]

Comment: Please do not add your code as an image, but as text. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

try this instead.

```
sudo node rfid.js
```